# VIdeojs not working on IE6

Tags: html, video, video.js

I downloaded the demo page from videojs.com but it's not working at all on IE6. Works fine on FF. I can'f view the videos from the web on IE6 so I think it's not waorking fine and it's not my fault.

Somebody can view videos with this tool on IE6? How?

Thanks

Comment: Your target market should not include IE6 users.

Comment: [In most countries, IE6 has less than 1% market share](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) (the notable exception being China). Just ignore IE6. It sucks, and *nobody* wants to support it any more. No modern web tools / frameworks / extensions are developed for it.

Comment: Forget it. Trying to make it work in such old browser (last stable release was **7 years ago**), is like trying to plug an HDMI into an analog CRT.
As @KonradRudolph points out, nothing is being developed for it (and nothing will be).
**Even Microsoft discourages its use,** check it out: [IE6Countdown](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/ie6countdown/)